# Django blog app with custom management system

Tags: django, django-admin, blogs, django-apps

We are looking for django blogging app that can be integrated into our existing project with more or less small integration effort. Our clients login to custom-made management system that uses django users framework for authentication. They do not have access to the admin.
We want our clients to have ability to manage their own blogs from our management system. So we are looking for django app that we can use to separately integrate the management system into ours.

Some of the common blogging apps are listed [here](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/blogs/)

However, most of the apps we looked at use the admin for blog management. Does anyone have any experience porting the management system of any of these apps to a custom-made management?

For completeness here are some major criteria for the blogging we are looking for:

- Should be django app to be integrated into existing project
- Should support Sites framework as we have more than 1 client that owns a separate domain
- RSS/Atom, tags and search are basically a must.
- Well separated management module that is either using custom-made views or if uses admin is considerably easy to integrate with non-admin custom-made management system.

In particular from the above blog list Zinnia looks promissing but we don't yet know how easy it would be to move the management site to use custom made non-admin views and templates. We do not necessarily look to integrate everything but for the bare minimum the ability to post or edit blog entries.

If anyone has any experience please share! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simple truth is that blogs are one of the easiest to write things out there, and, in a situation like yours, with so many parameters, writing your own is likely the best way to go.

Blogs have a well-defined, well documented data model. There isn't much to them, really, and Django provides all the parts you need without spending too much time on it.

Many (if not all) of the off-the-shelf Django blog packages I have experienced provide dozens of features you don't always need with these complex, "trying to be WordPress" models that just don't make sense for what a client *actually* needs. If they don't, they're so simple you could write them yourself in an afternoon.

Think about the data model. What does a blog really have?

- An object with a title, a publish date, a slug, an author, and an HTML content string.
- A taxonomy that attaches either tags and/or categories to a post.
- An RSS feed
- A commenting system with moderation.

The first two items are some of the simplest models you'll ever write. Django provides a robust RSS feed framework, and lastly, why manage your own commenting system when Disqus works so well?

In short, if you want the least amount of headaches, and something which integrates will with your existing CMS, just spend two days and write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I certainly share your opinion on several things, and in fact wrote couple of huge modules myself in a few hours with django instead of integrating others. This is to say we are not beginners in django and nor affraid of enjoing writting another feature from scratch all ourselves. However, with that said, we want to shortcut some testing cycles on something that is de facto standardized peice in any framework - blog.That's why we would consider rather integrating something solid rather write it from scratch! Active community is another huge factor towards reusing apps

Comment: So, why the search for a blog app? Time? Money?

Comment: Sorry the previous post was partially committed which kinda lost my next point. The answer is there